# Python PyQt Extending BuiltIn Widges

Tags: python, class

Defined a custom widget by extending a built-in QLineEdit by making it 'Double-Clickable':

```
class Clickable_LineEdit(QtGui.QLineEdit):

    def __init__(self, type, parent=None):
        super(DCLineEdit, self).__init__(parent)

    def mouseDoubleClickEvent(self, event):
        print "CLICK"
```

Now I can use this 'custom' **Clickable_LineEdit** widget to populate a main dialog window. It all works fine. But every time a double-click occurs it is registered OUTSIDE of main dialog window class... meaning all the main_dialog class's variables, all the data left behind and it is not available to **Clickable_LineEdit** class instance.

I wonder if it's possible to get doubleClick functionality from LineEdit without leaving a main dialog class.

EDITED LATER: 
Here is modified example from a post below:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui


class Clickable_LineEdit(QtGui.QLineEdit):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(QtGui.QLineEdit, self).__init__(parent)

    def mouseDoubleClickEvent(self, event):
        print "CLICK"

class Ui_Dialog(QtGui.QWidget):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(348, 195)
        self.lineEdit = Clickable_LineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 40, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Dialog", "Dialog", None,     QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))

    def runOnDoubleClick(self):
        print "DOUBLE CLICK"       

import sys
def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Ui_Dialog()
    ex.setupUi(ex)
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I have added a "**runOnDoubleClick**" function under a "Ui_Dialog()" class I would like to run every time a self.lineEdit widget is double-clicked (instead of mouseDoubleClickEvent() function). How would it be accomplished?

Comment: Well , according to what i understood , you want to a lineEdit that senses a doubleclick signal whenever lineEdit is doubleClicked, and no other doubleclick is sensed by your custom lineEdit ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well , according to what i understood , you want to a lineEdit that senses a doubleclick signal whenever lineEdit is doubleClicked .

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui


class Clickable_LineEdit(QtGui.QLineEdit):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(QtGui.QLineEdit, self).__init__(parent)

    def mouseDoubleClickEvent(self, event):
        print "CLICK"

class Ui_Dialog(QtGui.QWidget):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Dialog"))
        Dialog.resize(348, 195)
        self.lineEdit = Clickable_LineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 40, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit"))

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Dialog", "Dialog", None,     QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))

import sys
def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Ui_Dialog()
    ex.setupUi(ex)
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This seems to work for me .